# Forbid inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a parent class:

```
 class Animal
    {
    public :
       virtual void SetColor ( const string & col )
       {
         colour = col;
       }  

       virtual void Greeting ( const string & name )
       {
         cout << "Hi I'm Animal" << endl;
       }
    protected:
     string colour;
    };
```

Then i have a class Dog that inherit from class Animal.

For example :

```
class Dog : public Animal
{

};
```

If I'm not mistaken the Dog child class inherits everything from parent class Animal so in this case the Dog class inherits 2 methods `SetColor` and `Greeting` and also `string colour`.

> Is it possible to forbid method "Greeting" in parent class Animal to inherit?

Comment: No. Either don't put it on the base class, or override it on the derived class to do nothing.

Comment: It sounds like an XY-problem. What's the final purpose? Isn't enough reducing the visibility of the method by using `private`?

Answer (score 1):

You can force `Dog` to provide its own `Greeting`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Animal {
public:
    virtual void SetColor(const std::string & col)
    {
        colour = col;
    }

    virtual void Greeting(const std::string & name) = 0;

protected:
    std::string colour;
};

class Dog : public Animal {

    virtual void Greeting(const std::string & name) override
    {
        std::cout << "Hi I'm a dog. My name is " << name << ". I was forced to provide this function.\n";

    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Animal *ptr = new Dog();
    ptr->Greeting("Fluffy");
    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```